# RecyclerView always reloads the images in the rows when they come randomly

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

In my android application I am using a recyclerview.
I have an array with several images and in the viewHolder, I select a random number from that ArrayList and it is the image that is displayed in the row.
So far, everything is working perfectly.

```
   class ViewHolder(private val vb: NeoItemBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(vb.root) {
        fun bind(neoItem: NeoItem, context: Context) {
...
        val neoRandomName = getRandomNeoImageName()
            Glide.with(context)
                .load(vb.neoImage.setGlideVectorResourceImage(neoRandomName))
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                .into(vb.neoImage)
...}
```

*(setGlideVectorResourceImage it's just a extension function to load SVG of drawable with Glide)*

```
fun ImageView.setGlideVectorResourceImage(imageName: String?): Int {
    return resources.getIdentifier(imageName, "drawable", BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID)
}
```

The problem comes when I scroll the recyclerview, as you can imagine, the images are reloaded, and being random taken from the arrayList, when it shows again a row after scrolling the image has changed.

Well, I know there are many threads talking about this, but I have not found anything that works for me, the images are always reloaded.

Already somewhat desperate I have tried to verify if the imageView contains a drawable and if so, not to assign image to it, but the first elements continue changing.

I have tried recyclerView properties like ".getRecycledViewPool().setMaxRecycledViews(0, 0);" and many other things, but without success.
I have tried to do it from the onBindViewHolder... Nothing.

I don't know if my problem is from sending random images, I don't know.

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: I do not understand the problem. If you scroll the recycle view then texts and images are loaded in the view that comes in view. This has nothing to do with choosing a random image. It just has to be done. I think you should better explain what you think is your problem.

Comment: Sorry if I have not explained correctly.
When starting the recyclerView, in the first row, for example, a random image is loaded, I scroll down, leaving the first row of the screen and when returning up, the image of the first row has changed and is no longer the same as before, and so on with all the rows that come out and re-enter the screen.

Comment: It looks like you are generating a random image in the recyclerview adapter 'onBindViewHolder` method which gets called every time a new item needs to be shown in the recyclerview. I would generate the id for the random image before setting the items to the recyclerview if I was looking for them to always stay the same once generated

Comment: You should determine the random image even before you create the adapter for the recycle view. Just as you will have determined the text for every item in the view. So put it in the model list for the adapter just as you did with other data.